# What is an appropriate word for a "rerise"?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I'm wondering if there is a more appropriate term in English that describes a rise of something (like a nation) that has already achieved that status before, like  a second rise or re-rise.

Comment: Is there a nation anywhere to which this doesn't apply (i.e. that hasn't been great in the past)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We've been known to get some mileage out of the term **renaissance**.  ("Re-nascence", or rebirth.)

In contexts less fraught with pomp and circumstance we would probably speak of a **comeback**.

Answer (score 17):

How about **resurrection**? From the OED:

> …**3.** Revival or revitalization, esp. of a person who or thing which has fallen into inactivity, disuse, or obscurity; an instance of this.

Another similar option is **rebirth**:

> …**2.** A revival or renewal of a thing; a new beginning. Also as a mass noun.
>
> > *2005 Geographical Sept. 80/1* The grim heroism in defiance of Nazi and Soviet horrors and the miraculous rebirth of the modern state.

Comment: I especially like _rebirth_.

Answer (score 12):

In recent usage, "reascendance" is a [more common synonym](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=rerise,%20reascendance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) for "rerise".  Unlike some of the other suggestions here, it means exactly rising again, and does not imply starting over.

Comment: Try *relevation* then. Not to be confused with what happens when something is *re-levied*.

Comment: Although I would _generally_ not recommend this for "re-rise", reascendance _is_ particularly appropriate for nations.  (Not sure _why_ ascendance is so often used for nations, but it is.)

Answer (score 5):

Yet another [general reference](http://thesaurus.com/browse/resurgence?s=t) question.  <sup><sub>***SIGH!***</sub></sup>

> comeback, reawakening, rebirth, rebound, recovery, rejuvenation, renaissance, renascence, renewal, restoration, resurgence, resurrection, return, revitalization, revival, triumph

Comment: For some countries, [recrudescence](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recrudescence) might be the right word.

Comment: @jwpat7 That one makes me think of assorted *crudités* in my garden regrowing after a winter die-off. But perhaps that’s the intent.

Comment: I don't understand why the reference given is a *SIGH*.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Because questions answerable with a single link to a standard reference aren’t worth not closing as **General Reference**.

Answer (score 4):

Poetically, you could say such a nation

> rose like a phoenix from the ashes
>
> <sup>*[NOAD](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/phoenix?region=us&q=phoenix)*</sup>

Answer (score 4):

If you'll be using this in context, then just say "rose again".
As an aside, isn't re-raise used in Poker?

Answer (score 3):

"Reawakening" could be a useful word. "Resurrection" is another one.

If it doesn't have to be one word, saying that a specific object "rises again" isn't bad to say.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a nation you're referring to, and you don't mind a loanword, "[Risorgimento](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_unification)".

Comment: That's "resurgence" in English, which is not the worst word for the purpose either.

Comment: I used the Italian because tcrist already included "resurgence" in his answer, but mainly because it directs the reader to the example of Italy.

Comment: Oh, I see, I missed tcrist's usage.

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about how I would describe China as the former and future world leader, I would speak of the ***return*** or ***re-emergence*** of China as a world leader. I would be comfortable with someone else using ***reascendance*** but it would not be my first choice.  Google says *re-emergence* is [much more commonly used](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reascendance%2Creemergence%2C+re+-+emergence&year_start=1940&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) but I grant that *reascendence* is more precise.

Comment: I wouldn’t spell *reemergence* with neither a hyphen nor a diaeresis; *re-emergence* or the older *reëmergence* both look better than something that looks like a *remerger* of some sort.

Comment: @tchrist, I detest using diereses in English; I hesitate to use one even with naïve. It looks foreign and/or pretentious. I prefer _re-emergence_ to _reemergence_ but due to an issue with Google's Ngram viewer I mistakenly thought I was in a tiny minority. Re-checking, I see I'm not, so I edited my post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Rerise is not a regular or commonly used word. Rise serves both purposes most of the time.

The sun sets, and rises the next morning. You rise from sleep. The Phoenix rises from the ashes.

Similarly, dynasties that fell have risen after decades.

Rise can thus be used, with 'again' if needed.